# how to pass string return from javascript on asp.net page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to retrieve the string returned from the javascript to asp.net page? Let suppose there is a string returned from javascript function and there is a string variable on asp.net page, i want to assign the string return from javascript to the string variable in asp.net page.

There is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function networkInfo() {

                var wmi = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
                var service = wmi.ConnectServer(".");


                e = new Enumerator(service.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True"));


                for (; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
                    var s = e.item();
                    var macAddress = unescape(s.MACAddress);

                }
                return macAddress;
            }
        </script>
```

Page load of Asp.net page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string MacAddress;
    }
```

How could i do this?

Comment: make xmlhttprequest to that page

Comment: Is it clear to you how both ASP.NET and Javascript works? Once JS is executed, your ASP.NET code is gone... You would need some refreshing on the page (such as a form post, postback, etc), or an Ajax call.

Comment: Is it any way when my javascript is executed then the string macAddress returned from JS will assign to string MacAddress in asp.net? @LcSalazar

Comment: How can i make that call? @Royal Bg

Comment: @SahilMagoo when your js is executed and the variable populated, you should make xhrequest to the page sending that variable. Read about the XMLHttpRequest object in JS

Comment: Ok i do read about this, but for the short time is there any short way to do this? @Royal Bg

Comment: This is the shortest I can imagine

Comment: Can you suggest me some short way? @Royal Bg

Comment: Call `yourPage.aspx?macAddress={theMacADdressVariable}` then take that from the GET request in your C# code